# Whilw Updating the data using Python in MYSql , getting an error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I know there is some syntax error but not able to find it out. I made sure that it is getting insert in the right table.

```
column_update = input("Enter the column name where Data has to be updated: ")
update_data = input("Enter the new value: ")
column_name = input("Enter the column to get the row: ")
row_value = input("Enter the row value: ")

try:
    sql_update_query = """ UPDATE EmployeeList SET %s = %s WHERE %s = %s """
    my_cursor.execute(sql_update_query,params = (column_update,update_data,column_name,row_value))
    mydb.commit()
    print("Record Updated Successfully")

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to update record to database: {}".format(error))

finally:
    if (mydb.is_connected()):
        my_cursor.close()
        mydb.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

my table:

```
my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EmployeeList(user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,EMPID INT, Emp_Name VARCHAR(100),Designation VARCHAR(100), Role VARCHAR(100), Updated_by VARCHAR(100), LastUpdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW())")
```

user input details has to be given after running the script.

```
Enter the column name where Data has to be updated: Role
Enter the new value: Software
Enter the column name to get the row: EMPID
Enter the column value: 1
```

Error:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Role' = 'Software' WHERE 'EMPID' = '1'' at line 1
```

Comment: `EMPID` is an integer, so you probably have to cast it to an `int` before passing it as a argument to `execute`, like this: `if column_name == "EMPID": row_value = int(row_value)`

Comment: no , it didn't work on adding "if column_name == "EMPID": row_value = int(row_value)" . Also i tried executing data with other column, it displayed the same error."1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Role' = 'Soft' WHERE 'Emp_Name' = 'Abhinav'' at line 1"

Answer (score 1):

`sql_update_query = """ UPDATE EmployeeList SET %s = %s WHERE %s = %s;"""`

Add a semicolon(`;`) at last and check once if it worked.

Comment: Go and check is there the EMPID inputted available in your table or not. If not, insert the data first.

Comment: it is there. Same error I am facing when i am trying to give different condition i.e with Emp_Name

Comment: Have you entered the data first. The data which you are updating must be present in the table. Like- 5 12 Abhinav engineer senior engineer yesterday today etc. then access empid = 12 and update it.